# Netfilter in Linux Kernel is not getting packets in espresso bin (armada 3700) board

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have written a simple Kernel Module that monitors network traffic in a bridge mode. This module works on a desktop machine with two ethernet cards. Now I am trying to test it on a device called "espresso bin" created by Marvell.

Problem is my kernel module is not even seeing any packets on this board. Board layout shows something called "packet processor" but in linux kernel there is nothing related to that so I don't know how to interact with it. The mystery is that without me getting any packets the end client works fine in bridge mode.

Any suggestions on how to debug this? How to deal with hardware specific components in linux?

Thanks.